# Hardhar test Error : missing argument

Tags: solidity, hardhat, typescript

I am encounter missing argument error during run hardhat test .below is the script that trigger the error . My function MINT only have 1 argument to pass in and am passing number "1" into mint function .kindly advie

[image]

Test.script

```
 it("Should mint an ape", async () => {
    await FTPContract.setSaleState();
    const mintPrice = await FTPContract.MINT_PRICE();

    expect(
      await FTPContract.mint(1, {             <———  ************* passing number ‘1’
        value: mintPrice, })
    )
      console.log(`
      price: ${mintPrice}
     `);
  });
```

here my sol function mint :

```
function mint(uint numberOfTokens) public payable {     <——— *******Has 1 arguments
        uint256 ts = totalSupply();
        require(saleIsActive, "Sale must be active to mint tokens");
        require(numberOfTokens <= MAX_PUBLIC_MINT, "Exceeded max token purchase");
        require(ts + numberOfTokens <= MAX_SUPPLY, "Purchase would exceed max tokens");
    
        require(MINT_PRICE.mul(numberOfTokens) <= msg.value, "Ether value sent is not correct");

        for (uint i = 0; i < numberOfTokens; i++) {
             uint mintIndex = totalSupply(); /*follow BAYC mintape function*/
            if (totalSupply() < MAX_SUPPLY) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, mintIndex);
         
           }
        }
```

Comment: Hi all , anyone can help to brief where went wrong ? much appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setSaleState fucntion carry bolean value .so i chg to below.

```
await FTPContract.setSaleState('true');
```

Answer (score 0):

done . there was wrong argument pass in

Comment: Can you explain how you fix the test?